# Count elements by query in elasticsearch

Tags: c#, nest, elasticsearch

I inserted (batch) 616 elements to elasticsearch 1.5.1 using NEST C# library. I see that documents using Kibana but when I try counting them with NEST I have got always zero results.

```
var result = ElaticClient.Count<Bzp>(c => c
                .Query(q => q
                    .Range(r => r
                        .OnField(f => f.pubDate)
                        .Lower(to)
                        .GreaterOrEquals(from))
                    )
            );

return result.Count; //result is 0 but should be 616


StatusCode: 200, 
    Method: POST, 
    Url: http://localhost:9200/_count, 
    Request: {
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "pubDate": {
        "gte": "2015-04-29T00:00:00.000",
        "lt": "2015-04-30T00:00:00.000"
      }
    }
  }
}, 
    Response: {"count":0,"_shards":{"total":6,"successful":6,"failed":0}}
```

_

```
 ElasticClient.Count<Bzp>().Count //returns correct number of items
```

UPDATED:
All documents have date (pubDate field) April 29th 2015, 00:00:00.000 and IMHO should be count by the filter.

UPDATED:
Type registering is done by NEST

```
 ElasticClient.DeleteIndex("bzp");
            ElasticClient.CreateIndex("bzp");

            IdFieldMappingDescriptor desc = new IdFieldMappingDescriptor() {   };

            ElasticClient.Map<Bzp>(s => s.MapFromAttributes()
                .IdField(q=>q.Path("Id"))
                .TimestampField(z => z.Enabled(true).Path(q => q.Timestamp)));
```

And Bzp class

```
public class Bzp
    {
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime pubDate { get; set; }
     }
```

Comment: You have a range query in there. Are you sure you have documents matching the range?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with gte operator. Documents have field value set to  April 29th 2015, 00:00:00.000 and gte is "2015-04-29T00:00:00.000" so should be included in result

Comment: @marcinn may you share index mapping?

Comment: I updated how type is registered, there is no special mapping there.

Comment: @marcinn how do you index these documents?

Comment: Simple remove the range filter and see id it returns a count. If it does then you'll know it is a problem with your range filter.

Comment: @Rob I use bulk inserting, for me that is obvious that gte (greater or equal) for 2015-04-29T00:00:00.000 and documents with that value should work. When I chnage gte to 2015-04-28T00:00:00.000 it works ...